# How to generate multiple vectors given their distances

Tags: distance

Well, the title says it all. I'm looking for an algorithm that would generate multiple random vectors with given distances between them.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the site! There's not much context in your question. Here's a very trivial solution as a way of extracting your requirements: How about generating N unit vectors in a random order and then scaling them by 1/sqrt(2) times the desired distance D? This would give you orthogonal vectors. Notice that it requires that your dimensions are more than or equal to your desired number of vectors (D >= N). Such a solution might not be what you are looking for, so please expand your question with futher details to clarify the requirements.